# How to append dataframe in google big query with different schema in python?

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, pandas.dataframe.to-gbq

```
df1:

Name   Company  Desgn   Date         Salary
Rick   JKA      HR      2020-07-21   52
Nick   lka      Engg    2020-07-21   65
John   SDK      HR      2020-07-21   75
```

df2:

```
Name   Company  Desgn  
Rick   JKA      HR     
Nick   lka      Engg  
John   SDK      HR
```

Hi i need to write the df1 and df2 into a biq query table, basically appending both dataframe in a table using google cloud function. I am able to write df1 but it is giving error for df2.

```
code:
lst = [df1,df2]
for i in lst:
   i.to_gbq('dataset.table',project_id="project_id",if_exists='append')


error: "Please verify that the structure and data types in the DataFrame match the schema of the destination table."
```

Comment: Give a `table_schema` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_gbq.html   `[
    {
        "name": "name_of_the_column",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "description": "describe the column"
    }
]`

Answer (score 0):

You could have the same df structure and schema but use null values for date and salary

```
df2
Name   Company  Desgn   Date         Salary
Rick   JKA      HR      null         null
Nick   lka      Engg    null         null
John   SDK      HR      null         null
```

You could also append df1 with df2
df1:

```
Name   Company  Desgn   Date         Salary
Rick   JKA      HR      2020-07-21   52
Nick   lka      Engg    2020-07-21   65
John   SDK      HR      2020-07-21   75
Rick   JKA      HR      null         null
Nick   lka      Engg    null         null
John   SDK      HR      null         null
```

Comment: what if my df2 has extra column which df1 doesn't have?